# For-each loop in terraform

Tags: azure, for-loop, foreach, terraform, cloud

I have map of values which results the name of vnet and its resource group, I need to loop them in the data section of azure resource to fetch them dynamically

```
vnetID = ([for vnets in lookup(data.azurerm_resources.spokes, "resources", []) : lookup(vnets, "id")])
vnetinfo = { for details in local.vnetID: element(slice( split("/",details), 8, 9),0)  => {
                                                                                  "rg"    : element(slice( split("/",details), 4, 5),0),
                                                                                  "vnet"  : element(slice( split("/",details), 8, 9),0)
                                                            }
  }
```

The vnet info block outputs the following

```
"dev1-net" = {
    "rg" = "dev1-net-rg"
    "vnet" = "dev1-net"
  }
  "net-01" = {
    "rg" = "net-01-rg"
    "vnet" = "net-01"
  }
  "net-02" = {
    "rg" = "net-02-rg"
    "vnet" = "net-02"
  }
```

In the below block the name of the vnet and resource group should get looped from the above map of values

```
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "peeredvnets" {  
  foreach             = tomap(local.vnetinfo)
  name                = each.value["vnet"]
  resource_group_name = each.value["rg"]
}
```

I am doing the foreach syntax wrongly. Can someone help on how to achieve this. Need the name of vnet and its corresponding rg name using forloop in the above data loop

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 3):

The error message will help, but could be  `for_each` and not `foreach`